# IE compatibility: My Mini-Chat is Overflowing (Validated Markup)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

IE cross-compatibility issue. My website, [www.zerozaku.com](http://www.zerozaku.com/), is compatible with Chrome and Firefox, but IE has an issue with my Mini-Chat overflowing out of the box. Could anyone help?

P.S. I've only tested it on IE8, Firefox, Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be something about the `position:relative` throughout those elements.

Remove `position:relative` from the hb_container class on those inner divs and see if you can work from there. This will at least make the messages stay within the container, but the images still seem to have an issue.

Comment: Thanks bro, I didn't remove position: relative from the hb_container class since it would destroy my whole layout. Instead, I Google'd some more with the keywords "position relative" added to my search and found that the container for the positioned tags should also be relative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one issue is that when I load it in IE8 it goes into IE7 Standards mode . . . this can be due to your choice of !DOCTYPE.  When I switch it to IE8 mode, the bug seems to go away, so I suspect it's due to one of the many CSS bugs in IE7.

Another perhaps unrelated issue is that IE reports a JavaScript error in line 45 of default.js . . . I believe this is due to an extraneous comma on line 44